# Adding Links into a P5.js ball physics simulation

Tags: javascript, simulation, anchor, draggable, p5.js

I built an environment on p5.js, where basically a class of Balls is instanced to have them subjected to gravity and potentially dragged and thrown around.

I want to replace them with links instead.

I'm a bit confused about my next steps.

I managed to make this code:

```js
let numBalls = 13;
let spring = 0.05;
let gravity = 0.05;
let friction = -0.9;
let balls = [];
let menuData;


 function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  for (let i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
    balls[i] = new Ball(
      random(width),
      random(height),
      random(30, 40),
      i,
      balls
    );
  }
  noStroke();
  fill(255, 204);
  balls.forEach(ball => {
    ball.display();
  })
}
function draw() {
      background(0);
      balls.forEach(ball => {
        ball.collide();
        ball.move();
        ball.display();
      });
    }

    function mousePressed() {
      balls.forEach(ball => {
        if (ball.onBall(mouseX, mouseY)) ball.startDrag();
      });
    }

    function mouseDragged() {
      balls.forEach(ball => {
        if (ball.dragging) {
          ball.x = mouseX;
          ball.y = mouseY;
        }
      });
    }

    function mouseReleased() {
      balls.forEach(ball => {
        if (ball.dragging) {
          // Calculate the ball's new velocity based on how fast the mouse was moving when it was released
          ball.vx = (mouseX - ball.mousex) / 10;
          ball.vy = (mouseY - ball.mousey) / 10;

          // Set the ball's dragging property to false to indicate that it is no longer being dragged
          ball.dragging = false;
        }
      });
    }

    class Ball {
      constructor(xin, yin, din, idin, oin) {
        this.x = xin;
        this.y = yin;
        this.vx = 0;
        this.vy = 0;
        this.diameter = din;
        this.id = idin; // questo non c'è bisogno per la fisica
        this.others = oin;
        this.dragging = false;
      }

      onBall(x, y) {
        let dx = x - this.x;
        let dy = y - this.y;
        let dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return dist <= this.diameter / 2;
      }

      startDrag() {
        this.dragging = true;
        this.mousex = mouseX;
        this.mousey = mouseY;
      }

      collide() {
        for (let i = this.id + 1; i < numBalls; i++) {
          // Calculate distance and minimum distance between balls
          let dx = this.others[i].x - this.x;
          let dy = this.others[i].y - this.y;
          let distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
          let minDist =
            this.others[i].diameter / 2 + this.diameter / 2;

          // Check if balls are colliding
          if (distance < minDist) {
            // Calculate angle between balls
            let angle = atan2(dy, dx);
            // Calculate target position for balls to avoid overlap
            let targetX = this.x + cos(angle) * minDist;
            let targetY = this.y + sin(angle) * minDist;
            // Calculate force of collision using mass and elasticity
            let ax = (targetX - this.others[i].x) * spring;
            let ay = (targetY - this.others[i].y) * spring;
            this.vx -= ax;
            this.vy -= ay;
            this.others[i].vx += ax;
            this.others[i].vy += ay;
          }
        }
      }

      move() {
        if (this.dragging) {
          this.x = mouseX;
          this.y = mouseY;
        } else {
          // gravità
          this.vy += gravity;
          // update ball's position based on its velocity
          this.x += this.vx;
          this.y += this.vy;

          if (this.x + this.diameter / 2 > width) {
            this.x = width - this.diameter / 2;
            this.vx *= friction;
          } else if (this.x - this.diameter / 2 < 0) {
            this.x = this.diameter / 2;
            this.vx *= friction;
          }
          if (this.y + this.diameter / 2 > height) {
            this.y = height - this.diameter / 2;
            this.vy *= friction;
          } else if (this.y - this.diameter / 2 < 0) {
            this.y = this.diameter / 2;
            this.vy *= friction;
          }
        }
      }

      display() {
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.diameter, this.diameter);
      }
    }
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Now I want to replace those ellipses and have some HTML anchors instead in order to have a bunch of links bouncing around. What I mean by that is that now the object created is the ellipse, and I used that as a "placeholder" while I was building the rest of the code. My final aim is to have instead links created, I was thinking using creatA instead of ellipse could work, but apparently, it doesn't. here's the codepen for that: https://codepen.io/giambrodo/pen/poZeOgO

the issue in the codepen is that they are clearly getting created (the links) in a different way than the ellipses i don't get why and how tho. Within my project, that is bigger and presents actually multiple sketches (i use the instance p5.js method there) somehow the links are produced inside the first sketch, but that's another story i guess.

```
let as = createA('www.moodnothing.baby', 'baby');
as.position(this.x, this.y);
```

I also thought that I could just make the anchor outside, in the setup function, and modify the class within the `display()` method, using the class() function, but I'm not getting any results either.

Codepen if you need it:

https://codepen.io/giambrodo/pen/LYBxMZZ

Comment: You might want to toss in the setup and global variables from your codepen so the snippet is runnable in the post here. When you say you want links, are the balls supposed to be invisible? Assuming the links have text, those are basically rectangles, so the physics would change, right? Or do you want them to maintain the circle physics and overlap? When would these links trigger clicks, if normally they'd be dragged on click? Please elaborate on ["won't work"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @ggorlen ! I edited the post, hope it's now more understandable. To be more precise, the balls are getting replaced by the links, my struggle comes from the fact that I want to add an HTML element (the anchor) instead of the ellipse() function.

Comment: Instead of ripping out your otherwise pretty good question, why not add a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so others can benefit from your solution? If you have a new question, ask another question.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Sorry but i'm totally new to stack overflow. I'm gonna make the last edit so that I can leave it like that after it.

Comment: I posted another question that is more structured and comprehensive. I will archive this one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding HTML elements for every ball you add:

```
var linkElement = document.createElement("a");

linkElement.innerHTML = menuData.links[i].label;
linkElement.className = "link-element";
linkElement.id = "link-element";
linkElement.href = menuData.links[i].href;

document.body.appendChild(linkElement);
```

Then you can set the CSS of the link-elements. You'll want `position: absolute` so that they will overlay with the canvas.

```
#link-element {
  position: absolute;
  top:  0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Then to move the links around you can get each one and set its position equal to the balls:

```
const links = document.getElementsById("link-element");
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].style.left = this.x;
  links[i].style.top = this.y;
}
```